# Deleting all rows from table

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

I'm currently just messing around with mysql. I'm not able to delete all the rows from the table "amount" with this code `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FORM amount");` . With that code, I'm not even able to access my page.

```
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO freetexts (amount)
VALUES ('3')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT amount FROM freetexts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Amount: " . $row["amount"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM amount");

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$column = freetexts;`

You need to change

`mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM amount");`

to

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM  `$column` WHERE 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FORM amount");
```

Into

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM amount");
```

(misspelled `FROM`)

I also think you dont want to delete all records from the table `amount`, but just the found record in the table `freetexts`... So that would mean you need to alter the query. To give you further advice on something like this, update your question with a table-layout.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But it starts from Database(freetexts) and then inside is Table(amount) and then inside that is rows. I want to delete all the rows inside of the table(amount)

Comment: @Dgameman1 That's not what your code says... The database name is not disclosed, the table name is `freetexts` and there is a column in that table named `amount`...

Comment: Oh you're completely right. That's what I meant. table name is freetexts and the column amount. I want to get rid of everything inside the column ( amount). I want to remove everything I INSERTED to

Answer (score -1):

The BD probably has a protection denying the command to delete all rows without a condition clause.

Try this: TRUNCATE [table_name]

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn, "TRUNCATE [amount]");` doesn't delete anything at all. When I refresh I still see all the previous INSERT INTO's

Comment: delete the "[" and "]" from your query

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn, "TRUNCATE amount");`. I still see all the previous INTOs

Comment: Did you try: $conn->query("DELETE FROM amount"); instead of mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM amount"); ??